# When did mathematicians begin to use the letter x to denote unknown values?

Tags: ho.history-overview

When did mathematicians begin to use the letter x to denote unknown values ?
Gérard Lang

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.ted.com/talks/terry_moore_why_is_x_the_unknown?language=en

Comment: ...or don't. Florian Cajori's book "A history of mathematical notations" goes to great detail to explain how such popular theories came to be and how they are essentially not supported by any evidence. As far as the earliest _documented_ use, it goes back to Descartes, who simultaneously introduced y and z (and a,b,c) to denote unknowns. (pages 380-383 in Cajori's book)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104031/why-unknowns-are-usually-denoted-by-x?rq=1

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/30307/461