# What is the naming reason of poles in complex analysis?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ho.history-overview

A function $f: \textbf{C} \to \textbf{C}$ has a pole of order $k$ if $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k}}$ where $g(z)$ is a nonzero analytic function. Why do we call it poles?

Comment: Because poles stick up.  This seems a bit off-topic for MO.  It would be better suited to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because when $z \to z_0$, (the absolute value of) the function gets really big. Poles are tall objects.

Comment: Really?  My intuition here comes from dipoles.

Comment: According to "Earliest known uses of some words in mathematics: P" by Jeff Miller at http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html "The term POLE (in complex analysis) appears in Briot & Bouquet’s Théorie des fonctions elliptiques (1859, p. 15). The concept was used by Cauchy but the term was not. (Grattan-Guinness (1997, p. 388). See the Mathworld entry."

Comment: If you click on page 15 in the left frame of http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/Visualiseur?Destination=Gallica&O=NUMM-99571 you'll find at the top of the PDF 16. Pôles. "Lorsqu'une fonction $u$ est holomorphe dans une certaîne partie du plan, excepté en un point $z_1$, où elle devient infinie, de manière toutefois que la fonction 1/u reste holomorphe dans le voisinage de ce point, on dit que ce point est un _pôle_ ou un _infini_ de la fonction $u$."  Unfortunately, no further insight into the naming is given there.

Comment: (My previous comment is a quote from Briot & Bouquet's text, of course)

Comment: It's because they correspond to the north pole when considered as holomorphic functions onto the riemann sphere.

Comment: @Qiaochu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Examples_of_multipole_expansions

Comment: @muad: that seems like a real possibility.  Can anyone provide some historical evidence in favor of this?

Comment: I too think this would belong better on http://math.stackexchange.com - the fact the question has been asked here suggests that the user has not read the FAQ

Comment: Insert your favorite Polish joke here.

Comment: Why is this question not suited for MO, while a question like http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30081/origin-of-symbol-l-for-a-prime-different-from-a-fixed-prime is?
The term "pole" is now part of the language so that maybe we all think (as Kevin writes) "poles are tall objects".
But is the north pole a big object? Isn't it just a point? I would really like to see this question stay open and be resolved.

Comment: I, too, would like this question stay open. Please, count it as a vote against closing per old meta discussion.

Comment: @Nate: There was a transatlantic flight and the pilot and copilot dropped dead. A desperate flight attendant asked if anyone knew how to fly a plane. An old polish man said "Well, I used to fly planes in WWII, but nothing like this". When she brought him into the cockpit, his jaw dropped. There was so many buttons, levers, and fancy dials. "What's wrong?" the flight attendant asked. "I'm just a simple pole in a complex plane" he responded.

Comment: I hope this comment counts as a vote against closing too. The
question seems to be a hard one, well worth the attention of 
the MO community. I notice that the historian Judith Grabiner
asked this question on an internet forum in 1998, and she
apparently did not receive an answer.

Comment: @David: There is also the requirement to seat Polish passengers in the lefthand seats. The reason? For stability, you need all the poles in the left halfplane.

Comment: While the jokes here are pretty tame, the reason that there is whole genre of "Polish jokes" is related to ethnic stereotypes of Poles as stupid or unsophisticated.  I think it is pretty offensive to make even non-insulting Polish jokes given the history (for instance, would you tell Jewish or African-American jokes, even ones that weren't insulting?).

Comment: When my professor was just introducing poles he asked what we should call such a singularity, and I said, "We get to pick a name!?" And he said, "Sure go for it." And I said, "How about a vuvuzela!"

Comment: (after all, that's what they look like)

Comment: Note that the origin of complex analysis is very linked with cartography. In a conformal map of the Earth a pole is a point where the meridians/parallels system degenerates.

Answer (score 21):

The answer suggested by @muad’s comment is supported by both P. Ullrich ([1989, p. 163](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1018434)):

> The expressions “pole” and “polar singularity” were apparently first used in the 1865 book [“Vorlesungen über Riemann’s Theorie der Abel’schen Integrale”](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberr00neumgoog#page/n115)  of Carl Neumann (1832–1925): ***they are precisely the points that the function maps to the “pole” of the Riemann sphere.*** Neumann’s book, by the way, is also the first to develop the theory of the Riemann sphere, which Riemann himself had only presented in his lectures. (See Neuenschwander ([1978](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0315-0860(78)90047-2)) (...).)

(my emphasis) and A. Markushevich ([1996, p. 191](https://books.google.com/books?id=XTYDCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA191)):

> The classification of the singularities of an algebraic function as poles and critical points was carried out, for example, in the *Théorie des fonctions elliptiques* of Briot and Bouquet ([1875](https://archive.org/stream/thoriedesfonct00briouoft#page/15)). However, the term “pole,” as pointed out by E. Neuenschwander ([1978](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=490793)) was first used in this sense by K. Neumann in his *Vorlesungen über Riemann’s Theorie der Abelschen Integrale* ([1865](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberr00neumgoog#page/n115)) in connection with the fact that the point at infinity was depicted as the pole of the sphere in this book.

The quoted article of Neuenschwander notes that the histories by Brill-Noether ([1894, p. 170](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002114283&physid=PHYS_0199)) and Osgood in the *Encyklopädie* ([1901, p. 18](https://archive.org/stream/encyklomath202encyrich#page/n43)) both miscredit Briot and Bouquet. So does (as of now) the [*earliest uses*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html) site — quoting an edition ([1859](https://archive.org/details/thoriedesfoncti00goog)) where the word *pôle* does not even appear.

I have wondered if Neumann was perhaps inspired by prior uses of “pole” for [homographies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Poles_of_the_transformation) or [inversions](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_cTJMCIzdUC&pg=PA100&dq=pole),
$$
f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\qquad\text{or}\qquad f(z) = a+\frac k{\bar z-\bar a},
$$
(presumably then traceable to [Stubbs](https://books.google.com/books?id=dzxZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA338&dq=pole), [Chasles](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_SZIKAAAAYAAJ#page/n574), [Servois](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_SZIKAAAAYAAJ#page/n373),...) but couldn't find solid evidence.

Answer (score 16):

As Martin O remarks, the French word "pôle" (or the German "Pol") does not include the meaning "pillar", that's why the explanation "looks like a pillar" seems a bit dubious, at least to me.

Being a native German speaker, I have always associated the word "pole" to the *electrical pole* and thus to the function $\frac1{r^2}$. It seems entirely natural to me to use this special example as a prototype for any singularity of a (complex) function.

Comment: According to the online etymological dictionary, the English word pole derives from the Latin word palus meaning stake. So the term could be handed down to us from when mathematicians still wrote in Latin. The term could also derive from Greek, polos (axis of a sphere), or it could be a coincidence. Simply because the direct cognate of a word in German doesn't correspond to the current meaning of an English word doesn't mean the words didn't have similar meanings long ago. The English word table is related to the German word Tafel even though Tafel only infrequently means table.

Comment: A word derived from the Latin palus=stake does exist in German: Pfahl. In contrast, the Greek word polos becomes polus in Latin. So it appears that the North pole and the pole that is used to mark it actually have different etymological origins.

Comment: it's translated into Russian as полюс (polus) - suggesting Latin root, and the only meaning is for  North/South geographic poles, +/- of batteries, etc.

Answer (score 11):

This may be apocryphal folk etymology, but I always thought it was because if you plot, or envision plotting, the surface z = |f(x + iy)|, at poles of f, the surface, if you imagine it sitting over the xy plane, looks like it is being supported by a really tall pole.  Like a circus tent.  I have no citations to support this belief, but I must have gotten it from somewhere.  Anyway it makes a good deal of sense.

I'm posting this, despite not having an MO account, because genuinely can't understand why nobody has posted it yet.  (Nikita's "because poles stick up" comes close, but seems to have been drowned out by posts about poles being "big", or invocations of the north pole, which seem to be entirely different explanations.)

Comment: This is a nice explanation, but I don't think that this is the correct one since in French (and German) the translation of your 
use of pole would not be "pôle" (or "Pol").
I guess it is rather related to the poles of a magnet.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation that would also make sense in French and German is that the value of a function at a pole is equal to infinity, the North pole of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: May be this somehow related to the behavior of magnetic compass, when you approaching to the magnetic pole? The pointer of compass tends to be vertical at pole.

Comment: Upon reading the question, I figured something very close to Faisal's comment above. Poles are where $f(z)$ is the (North) Pole in the Riemann sphere. This, by the way, would make sense also in Italian (where "polo" is used both for Earth's poles and for, well, poles of meromorphic functions, whereas the "tall pole" in anon's answer is a "palo"). 

Comment: On second thought, I'm not so sure. For instance because the sphere has two poles (and for the Riemann sphere interpretation a zero should be called a "southern pole").

So I thought that maybe the two names are not directly related and they both derive from some other older meaning of the term. So, a relevant side question may be "why the Earth's poles are called such and who was the first to name them so?".

Is a question for cartographers too off topic for MO? :-)

Comment: I thought this too, but as a native English speaker I didn't even stop to remember that the terminology originated in other languages.

Comment: @Martin: According to the online etymological dictionary, the English word pole derives from the Latin word palus meaning stake.  So the term could be handed down to us from when mathematicians still wrote in Latin.  The term could also derive from Greek, polos (axis of a sphere), or it could be a coincidence.  Simply because the direct cognate of a word in German doesn't correspond to the current meaning of an English word doesn't mean the words didn't have similar meanings long ago.  The English word table is related to the German word Tafel even though Tafel only infrequently means table.

Comment: @Peter: According to the online etymology dictionary, the two meanings of pole come from two different latin words: palus respectively polus (similar as in Italian). So my guess is that at the time of invention of the term the words were different. Still you might be right that originally all these words have its origin in the same greek word.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary has separate entries for the two meanings of pole. For "pole" as in "north pole" it says: Middle French *pole*, Middle French, French *pôle* celestial pole (c1220 in Old French), terrestrial pole (c1377 or earlier; see also note below), either extremity of the main or longitudinal axis of an organ or cell (1830 in the passage translated in quot. 1834 at sense 11) and its etymon classical Latin *polus* the end of the axis on which the celestial spheres were believed to revolve, the pole star, the sky, the heavens, ... [cont'd]

Comment: ... in post-classical Latin also point at the end of a magnet (1269 in Petrus Peregrinus) < ancient Greek πόλος pivot, axis, axis of the celestial sphere (Plato), end of this axis (Aristotle), the sky, in Hellenistic Greek also the pole star < an ablaut variant (o-grade) of the Indo-European base of πέλεσθαι to be in motion (see palinodia n.).

Comment: However, for the other notion of "pole" the OED mentions only the Latin palus and says nothing about Greek.

Comment: In fact "pole" (1) as in "pole-position", from "palus" (=stake), and "pole" (2) as in "North pole", from "πόλος" (=pivot/turning point), are different words with even different PIE roots. The complex analysis one is (2); in particular, the interpretation of "pole" as "stick shaped" graph of a real valued function seems incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

This picture

[image][(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jahnke_gamma_function.png)

should make it clear why they are called poles.

Comment: These pictures used to be included in many complex analysis texts a few decades ago. I haven't encountered them in any of the recent book, though. 

Answer (score 10):

According to these [pages](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html), the earliest known appearance of the term pole might be in  [*"Théorie des fonctions elliptiques"*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/Visualiseur?Destination=Gallica&O=NUMM-99571) (1875, p. 15) by Briot and Bouquet:

> Lorsqu'une fonction $u$ est holomorphe dans une certaine partie du plan, excepté en un point $z_1$, où elle devient infinie, de manière toutefois que la fonction $\frac{1}{u}$ reste holomorphe dans le voisinage de ce point, on dit que ce point est un *pôle* ou un *infini* de la fonction $u$.

They don't provide any motivation for this choice of a term though.

By the way, in their first memoir on the subject, [*"Étude des fonctions d'une variable imaginaire"*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k995680.r=briot.langEN) (1856), Briot and Bouquet refer to a pole of a function only as *un infini du degré fini*.

Comment: To add to this, I have looked at the pages referred to for other words and they seem well-researched to me (who is not a mathematical historian).

Comment: "When a function u is holomorphic in a certain part of the plane, except for one point z_1, where it becomes infinite, similar to the function 1/u which remains holomorphic at the neighborhood of that point, we say that this point is a pole or an infinity of the function u." In the earlier paper, it's called "an infinity of finite degree".

Comment: I posted this as a comment to the main question a while back, but it apparently got buried...

Comment: @jc: I haven't noticed your previous comment, sorry. I'm making this answer Community Wiki.